# Index strategy on new tables - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

What should be the index strategy to be followed when I am creating a brand new DB and/ or tables. As I will not have any user queries to analyse or requirements to find which column is being used mostly. What should be my index strategy/ (which columns should frame the clustered and which columns should participate in Non-Clustered)? How should I go ahead in this scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this. An indexing strategy is usually built based on a known (or presumed) set of queries and update operations. If you're building a database where only insert operations occur, then either no index, or a single (clustered) index based on an incrementing value would be most efficient. It won't work when you start querying, but you **can't** build an indexing strategy without knowing what type of queries you need to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything in advance, the best you can do is to generously apply indexes. This will lower your write performance in a major way, but at least you can handle unexpected queries well.

Answer (score 1):

Index the columns that are currently used in your functions/stored procedures. Once your application starts getting used you could adjust accordingly and run the tuning wizard.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to new development projects versus production support it is hard to have an absolute answer where indexing falls into the priority list.  In terms of a new development project, it would be wise to spend equal time on building the database design, the indexing strategy and the data access code.  Without it, the application can become a maintenance nightmare requiring a great deal of attention in the production environment.  In many respects this is easier said than done if the database is just considered a black box that is expected to run forever without any attention.  If you are faced with that issue, then it is necessary to change that mentality first and make sure the time, energy and resources properly address the database needs moving forward.

For production applications, reviewing the indexes and query plans should be a high priority when a performance problem is occurring.  In many respects changing or adding indexes should be one of many items that are reviewed, analyzed, tested and deployed as opposed to considering indexes a magic bullet to resolve performance problems.

Another important consideration with the indexes is that as the application changes, the indexes may need to change as well.  Do not consider the indexes stagnant, but rather review the code with index implications in mind.  So as the application changes do not be afraid to change, test and deploy an improved indexing strategy.

You can read further here http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1452/sql-server-index-checklist/